# Best way to overwrite child element for pseudo-elements (e.g., :before)

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-specificity

I have a very complex drop-down menu with different icons for almost each section and sub-section, and it is causing specificity issue that has gone to a point that I found it hard to control.

Example, in the parent menu, I have something like this:

```
ul.parent .t1 a:before {background-position: 12px -49px;width:34px;}
```

In the children menu for `.t1`, there isn't `:before` pseudo-element, but it's picking up the parent's pseudo-element.

What I do right now, is adding a new class to the sub UL, and declared it:

```
ul.sub-child li a:before {width:0!important}
```

Due to the complexity of the menu, I'm wondering if there is a clever way to overwrite specificity.

Comment: First of all note that you could remove the generated content by `content: none` declaration. Second, I'd go with direct descendant selectors `A > B` rather than descendant selectors `A B` which would help to distinguish the nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only style direct children of an element, use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors) `>`.

In your case I don't know the exact HTML structure, but something like this:

```
ul.parent .t1 > a:before {
    /* CSS rules */
}
```

This only applies the rules to the `a:before` of direct children of `.t1`, not all of them down the line.